# Magento API v2 regarding inserting shipment numbers and tracking numbers

Tags: magento-1, api

I am  new to magento and its web services,
Can any body help me to insert multiple records at single request by consuming magento web services through other applications(Eg: Dynamics Nav ERP system).
Actually when we send multiple records by given method `salesOrderShipmentAddTrack` in to magento to insert Tracking numbers, it is able to send only single record .
So is there any need to change any settings are change the method code or else anywhere.
Please any body can help this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I've gone through magento documentation, no such method exist to insert tracking numbers in bulk. You could run the method call inside an iterative loop (for, foreach or while)

Answer (score 3):

Magento SOAPv1 API offers the possibility to call methods with `multiCall`, with SOAPv2 API you are not able to use it.

An example for multiCall is:

```
$result = $client->multiCall($session, array(
     array('sales_order_shipment.addTrack', array(
                                             'shipmentIncrementId' => '200000001',
                                             'carrier' => 'ups',
                                             'title' => 'UPS',
                                             'trackNumber' => '123123')
                                             ),
     array('sales_order_shipment.addTrack', array(
                                             'shipmentIncrementId' => '200000002',
                                             'carrier' => 'post',
                                             'title' => 'Austrian Post',
                                             'trackNumber' => '112233')
                                             ),
     array('sales_order_shipment.addTrack', array(
                                             'shipmentIncrementId' => '200000003',
                                             'carrier' => 'dhl',
                                             'title' => 'DHL',
                                             'trackNumber' => '987654')
                                             ),
));
```

The main difference between SOAPv1 and SOAPv2 is that instead of using the methods call and multiCall, SOAPv2 has its separate methods for each action. 
The advantage of SOAPv2 API is the possibility to work in WS-I compliant mode (for example if you want to generate stubs of the soap service).

If performance is an issue, you should check your **WSDL cache** setting under System -> Configuration -> Magento Core Api -> Enable WSDL Cache